# Two-column, multiple-row CSS layout with special requirements

Tags: html, css

The following layout gives me headaches. No tables should be used and the second column *must* be a single element containing *all* the rows. Rows should start at the same height across the two columns. Both columns are fluid with a fixed ratio.

How would I achieve this using HTML and CSS? I would rather prefer a semantically elegant solution without any JavaScript.

```
+--------++------------------------+
|  Row 1 ||  Row 1                 |
|        ||                        |
+----------------------------------+
|  Row 2 ||  Row 2                 |
|        ||  xxxxxxxxxxx           |
|        ||  xxxxxxx               |
|        ||  xxxxxxxx              |
+----------------------------------+
|  Row 3 ||  Row 3                 |
|  xxxx  ||                        |
|  xxxxx ||                        |
|  xx    ||                        |
+----------------------------------+
|  Row 4 ||  Row 4                 |
|  xxxxx ||  xxxxxxxxxxxxx         |
|        ||  xxxxxxxx              |
|        ||                        |
+--------++------------------------+
```

**Why does the second column have to be a single element containing all rows?**

I need to apply a box-shadow enclosing the whole column height.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
```

Comment: ***second column must be a single element containing all the rows*** this is a strange requirement, not special.

Comment: `box-shadow` will be applied to the right column, that's why it has to be one continuous element.

Comment: if so you can have some workaround to render the box-shadow, using a single element for the second column while keeping all the cells' heights equal (in the same row) is not easy to do with just HTML and CSS.

Comment: I already expected that… I will probably come up with some hacky solution but please feel free to share a more elegant way if you happen to know so.

Comment: it depends on the flexibility of your table, such as if the second column's width is fixed, we can just use a pseudo-element to render the box-shadow.

Comment: It also depends on the type of `box-shadow` you plan to apply. Please share your CSS rule.

Comment: Thanks so far guys, I updated the question with some more details.